# Snap window to corner

Tags: unity

Using Ubuntu 12.04LTS precise. On my old laptop I could use CTRL+ALT+numpad to snap windows to corners. But my new laptop does not have a num pad on the keyboard. Is there an alternative shortcut? (Or indeed, anyway to snap a window to the corner?)

Edit: there is no option on my laptop to enable a numpad via a fn key by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager). Search for "compiz" in the Unity Dash, or start with `ccsm` from the command-line.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

This windows will open. Type `grid` in "Filter" box and from right pane select "Grid" option.

[image]

Then this window will open.

[image]

Just click on each button (point 1) and then into "`Edit <Key name>`" window, choose `Grab key combination` and press your alternative key, then click Ok and enjoy

But don't forget, read **/!\** Warning **/!\** and don't change nothing more!!

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what I did in that tool, but I got back my Alt+Ctrl keys in Eclipse, instead of having it snapping the window to the top/bottom left corner. Thanks!